# Bind selected value of a multicolumn combobox inside DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

**Working Example :**

I have a table called groups as shown below :

[image]

After looking at the image above I think you might have understood that primary key and foreign key exist in the same table. I think this is what developers call cyclic reference.

In MainWindow.xaml I have a DataGrid which contains three columns namely Group Name, Parent Name, Description. The xaml looks like :

```
<Window .......>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <self:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" TabIndex="1">

        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Group Name" Width="2*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Parent" Width="2*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParentID, Converter={StaticResource GroupIDToGroupNameConverter}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.GroupsCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding ParentID}"
                                  SelectedValuePath="GroupID"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="GroupName"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description" Width="2*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </power:PowerDataGrid.Columns>

    </power:PowerDataGrid>

</Window>
```

Now I have a ViewModel called MainWindowViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SampleDBContext sampleDBContext = new SampleDBContext();
        Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
        GroupsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Group>(from g in sampleDBContext.Groups select g);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Group> _groups;
    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups
    {
        get
        {
            return _groups;
        }
        set
        {
            _groups = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Groups");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Group> _groupsCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Group> GroupsCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupsCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupsCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupsCollection");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertryName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertryName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

GroupIDToGroupName.cs //Converter

```
public class GroupIDToGroupName : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            SampleDBContext sampleDBContext = new SampleDBContext();
            return (from g in sampleDBContext.Groups
                    where g.GroupID == (int)value
                    select g.GroupName).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SampleDBContext sampleDBContext = new SampleDBContext();
        return (from g in sampleDBContext.Groups
                where g.GroupName == (string)value
                select g.GroupID).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

In App.xaml :

```
<self:GroupIDToGroupName x:Key="GroupIDToGroupNameConveerter" />
```

**My Case (Very similar to above sample):**

I just want to use a Multi-Column ComboBox instead of simple ComboBox inside DataGrid.

I have two tables :

[image]

Now I have set up my code exactly as the above mentioned code.

I have added an extra class called GroupIDAndNameWithCorrespondingEffect like :

```
public class GroupIDAndNameWithCorrespondingEffect : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _groupID;
    public int GroupID
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupID;
        }

        set
        {
            _groupID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupID");
        }
    }

    private string _groupName;
    public string GroupName
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupName;
        }

        set
        {
            _groupName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupName");
        }
    }

    private string _correspondingEffect;
    public string CorrespondingEffect
    {
        get
        {
            return _correspondingEffect;
        }

        set
        {
            _correspondingEffect = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CorrespondingEffect");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Changes in my ViewModel :

I removed the property GroupsCollection and all its references and added a new property called GroupIDAndNamesWithCorrespondingEffects as below :

```
private ObservableCollection<GroupIDAndNameWithCorrespondingEffect> _groupIDAndNamesWithCorrespondingEffects;
public ObservableCollection<GroupIDAndNameWithCorrespondingEffect> GroupIDAndNamesWithCorrespondingEffects
{
    get
    {
        return _groupIDAndNamesWithCorrespondingEffects;
    }
    set
    {
        _groupIDAndNamesWithCorrespondingEffects = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("GroupIDAndNamesWithCorrespondingEffects");
    }
}
```

And in the Constructor :

```
List<GroupIDAndNameWithCorrespondingEffect> _GroupIDAndNamesWithCorrespondingEffects = (
                                                                                                 from g in sampleDBContext.Groups
                                                                                                 select new GroupIDAndNameWithCorrespondingEffect
                                                                                                 {
                                                                                                     GroupID = g.GroupID,
                                                                                                     GroupName = g.GroupName,
                                                                                                     CorrespondingEffect = g.Effect.Effect1
                                                                                                 }
                                                                                             ).ToList();

            GroupIDAndNamesWithCorrespondingEffects
                = new ObservableCollection<GroupIDAndNameWithCorrespondingEffect>(
                                                                                _GroupIDAndNamesWithCorrespondingEffects.Where
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        u => !GetAllChildren(25)
                                                                                                .Select(x => x.GroupID)
                                                                                                .Contains(u.GroupID)
                                                                                    ).ToList()
                                                                            );
```

In my MainWindow.xaml I have added a resource as follows :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffectsCollection" Source="{Binding GroupIDAndNamesWithCorrespondingEffects}" />    
</Window.Resources>
```

Inside Grid's Resources :

```
    <Grid.Resources>

        <CompositeCollection x:Key="Items">
            <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Background="#FF2A2A2A" Foreground="White">
                <Grid TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.Children>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Group Name" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Effect" />
                    </Grid.Children>
                </Grid>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffectsCollection}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:GroupIDAndNameWithCorrespondingEffect}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Children>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding CorrespondingEffect}" />
                </Grid.Children>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Grid.Resources>
```

And I changed the ItemsSource of ComboBox to ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Items}".

**Problems :**

When I run the program ComboBox displays all the items correctly. Also, two columns with headers are displayed. Its working fine, but when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>TAB</kbd>, then focus remains in the same cell and the comboBox's text displays namespace of GroupIDAndNameWithCorrespondingEffect

Here is the image of Problem :

[image]

**Sample:**

Incase if somebody wants to check the sample then it is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bU01iWDBlb09WRVE/edit?usp=sharing). And database files are available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bQzdWOWc4Q2tvY1E/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I am not able to run the sample provided due to no SQL server here. could you provide a sample with static data, which is not dependent on SQL etc?

Comment: I don't know how to create those relationships in my code, so I have used ef to fetch those relations from database. So, my data is coming from database instead of static data source. I have uploaded my database files here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bQzdWOWc4Q2tvY1E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @pushpraj are you able to run the project now?

Comment: not yet as I need to install sql server first, I'll try it later.

Comment: @pushpraj Thanks. If you find any problems in running the project, please let me know.

Comment: I am not able to import the DB as it is newer version (http://imgur.com/WHaWDHM) then mine. perhaps you could export the same to SQL files. I have SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57980/discussion-between-pushpraj-and-vishal).

Comment: @pushpraj Sorry, I did not see your comments.

Comment: @pushpraj were you able to run the project successfully?

Comment: yes I am able to run it but not able to reproduce the issue, see http://imgur.com/3kahwy7. I update the same in chat discussion too

Comment: @pushpraj Yes you are absolutely correct. Can you enter the data as I say to reproduce the issue? Please enter some text in first column and then press enter. So you will move to next cell. Now select any group and press enter. By doing this you can exactly see the problem listed above.

Comment: @pushpraj Big Thanks for trying to help me and giving your precious time. I have got my answer after working on it for many days. For how I solved it, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!!!!

I declared the resource with `key="Items"` in Grid. So, when I Check for `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` in `PreviewKeyDown` event of DataGrid, it gives me `-1` and so my logic works as unexpected. Also, at this time I get `ComboBox.Items.Count = 0`.

So I just changed the place of declaration of the resource. I mean I deleted `Grid.Resources Section` and in `ComboBox.Resources section` I wrote the same code. Now it is working fine. Now in `PreviewKeyDown of DataGrid`, I get the expected `SelectedIndex of the ComboBox` as well as `ComboBox.Items.Count is equal to the Count in Source`.

I don't know why this happens? As I have used it as `DynamicResource` I expect it to work even if it is declared in Grid.Resources section.

Comment: @pushpraj thanks. Can you answer the question in my answer. Now datagrid gives me the expected behaviour but why it does not work in Grid.Resources section?

Comment: To me it look like an issue of template resolving strategy while a cell enters in edit mode via certain steps. To avoid such issues do opt for StaticResource instead of DynamicResource which would fail if not able to resolve hence you may not see the full name of class instead of expected output.

Comment: @pushpraj Thanks for your suggestion. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ... maybe your combobox just needs IsEditable = false. IsEditable = True causes comboboxes to show namespaces instead of the text.

Comment: But I need IsEditable behavior of combobox to be true.

Comment: If you need IsEditable = True Then maybe putting the text to be displayed inside the comboboxitem tag with Textsearch.Text might do it:  <ComboBoxItem TextSearch.Text="here ist the text to be displayed">. This must be exactly the same text as 'inside' the comboboxitem.

Comment: I am 100% sure that my binding needs to be changed. But I don't know the correct property of model to be binded.

Comment: It must not be the same text. It can be any text, and it will be displayed, I found.

Comment: Sorry... I am not able to understand your above comment.

Comment: I just meant that any text you assign to TextSearch.Text will be displayed instead of the text(binding) within your comboboxitem. TextSearch.Text also takes bindings.

Comment: Also, i have checked my program after setting IsEditable to false. Now my program goes into never ending loop. If you want to check then please have a look at my sample project provided in question.

Comment: Why should I setup binding on TextSearch.TextPath?

Comment: somewhere in your code you have <self:GroupIDToGroupName x:Key="GroupIDToGroupNameConveerter" />. I just fell over 'Conveerter' instead of Converter.

Comment: That's a spelling mistake. But everywhere i used ee instead of e. I noticed that before posting this question. And I am sure that it will not be a part of my problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I have got my answer after working on it for many days. For how I solved it, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is in http://www.shujaat.net/2010/08/wpf-editable-combobox-with-datatemplate.html

```
TextSearch.TextPath="GroupName"
```

Another way would be to provide a DataTemplate to the ComboBox's ItemTemplate

```
<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But i have already used TextSearch.TextPath. Take a look at my sample project

Comment: Did you try the ItemTemplate?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I have got my answer after working on it for many days. For how I solved it, see my answer.